# SFDX deploying Contact Sharing rules on a fresh deployment

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx, ci

I'm trying to deploy a Contact sharing rule into a new scratch org and I get following error.

> Deploying sharing rule xxxxx not supported for object Contact since
>   it's org wide default is 'Controlled By Parent'

My presumption is, this is due to Contact sharing is set as `Controlled by Parent` by default.

My issue is I'm trying to run this in a automated script (CI) and I can't manually change this and then do a push separately.

I have also tried to convert the source into `mdapi` format and deploy, but still get the same error.

Just wondering whether you guys have come across this before and there's solution/workaround?

Many thanks.

Comment: Changing sharing type for contact would be one time activity on destination org, after that pushes would work fine.

Comment: @Raul yes I agree but I want to automate it so settling sharing manually is not an option.

Comment: Org-wide defaults are deployable by the MDAPI, but they need to be deployed in a separate step, before the sharing rules themselves. If you're using some general-purpose CI tool like Jenkins, you could script out something that deploys org-wide defaults as a separate build step that fires first, then chain that with your original deployment step.

Answer (score 2):

Please try setting sharing rules your scratch def and see if it works.

```
"objectSettings": {
    "opportunity": {
      "sharingModel": "private"
    },
    "account": {
      "sharingModel": "private"
    },
    "contact": {
      "sharingModel": "private"
    },
    "case": {
      "sharingModel": "private"
    }
  }
```

Comment: I applied same fix for my project, but it still fails randomly, like in 30% of our CI execution I receive error message that OP posted (just about Asset object). Do you know what could be the reason of random failures?